# Run exe against list of files and place output in directory named after input file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a group of txt files in Directory A and an exe and batch file in Directory B. How can I create a batch file that runs that exe against the txt files and places the output into newly created directories named after the input txt file in Directory B.

Answer:

```
for %%i in (C:\example\DirectoryA\*) do md ".\%%~ni" & example.exe %%i ".\%%~ni"
```

Comment: Was able to figure it out myself.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to write your own answer and accept it. You should definitely do that, just in case somebody else has the same problem that you do.